# Nth child odd and even do not work together

Tags: css, transform, css-selectors

I am trying to add some randomisation by making elements rotate slightly based on being odd or even.

[See JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Essentially there is a style applied to `odd` and `even` using `nth-child` which should make every other one rotate at a different angle but it does not seem to apply the second...

```
ul.polaroidGrid li .polaroid:nth-child(even){
    transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-moz-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-o-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-ms-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
}

ul.polaroidGrid li .polaroid:nth-child(odd) {
    transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg) ;

}
```

Example HTML for one item

```
<li>
        <div class="polaroid">
        <img src="images/makers/getbetter.jpg" />
        <span class="polaroidTitle">Get Better Clothing</span>
        <a href="http://www.getbetterclothing.com/" target="_blank">getbetterclothing.com</a>
        </div>
        <p>Clothing which draws inspiration from childhood toys and nature using fun illustrative styles.</p> 
    </li>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle link doesn't have anything saved in it.

Answer (score 2):

Each `.polaroid` is the first and only child of its parent, so they're all odd.

You want the odd and even `li`s.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that must be something like this:

```
ul.polaroidGrid li:nth-child(even) .polaroid{

}

ul.polaroidGrid li:nth-child(odd) .polaroid {

}
```